# How do I show the preview of the file (jpeg/png) selected in a new HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

What I am trying to do is pass the selected file object from the current html page **(current.html)** to another html page **(preview.html)** and show a preview of the image selected, there.

**current.html**:

```html
Upload image: <input type="file" accept=".jpeg , .png" id="img"><br>
<button id="button" onclick = "submit()" >Register</button>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
   
   var file=document.getElementById("img").files[0];
   document.cookie="Image =" + file + ";" + "path=/";
   window.location.href="preview.html";
   
</script>
```

**preview.html**

```html
 Image: <img src="" alt="" id="image"><br>
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var arr=document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         
       var c = arr[i].split('=');
       if(c[0].trim() == 'Image'){
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function() {
             document.getElementById("image").src = reader.result;
          }
          if (c[1]) { reader.readAsDataURL(c[1]); }
       }
    }
</script>
```

But no image shows up in **preview.html**. Instead I keep getting an error in the console tab:

```
uncaught typeerror: failed to execute 'readasdataurl' on 'filereader': parameter 1 is not of type 'blob'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think It should be reader.onload = evt => { img.src = evt.target.result }

Comment: Nope, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting FileObject in cookie will not work. Try converting it to base64 string and do something like this.

```html
<input type="file" accept=".jpeg , .png" id="img" /><br />

<button id="button" onclick="submit()">Register</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var submit = () => {
    var file = document.getElementById("img").files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      localStorage.setItem("Image", event.target.result);
      window.location.href = "preview.html";
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
</script>
```

preview.html

```html
Image: <img src="" alt="" id="image" /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
  const image = localStorage.getItem("Image");
  document.getElementById("image").src = image;
</script>
```